# How to use Laravel 4 localization methods in Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way for you to use Laravel `trans()` or `Lang::get()` method using (lang folder) in AngularJS app?

Laravel view that displays an angular view with multiple controllers.

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I have in `public_html` folder all my templates for my app.

Answer (score 0):

With the default structure of a Laravel app you can't access the `app/lang` directory. However, you could write a grunt task or a Laravel command, that process all you language files and copy the results in your `public` directory to make it publicly available for your Angular app.